# reading a large number from excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am reading a xlsx file with pandas and a Column contain 18 digit number for example `360000036011012000`

after reading the number is converted to `360000036011011968`

my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")
```

I also tried converting the column to string but the results are same

```
df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx",dtype = {"column_name":"str" })
```

also tried with `engine = 'openpyxl'`

also if the same number is in csv file there is no problem reading works fine but I have to read it from excel only.

Comment: Might be silly solution but would it be possible to split the int as sum of two cells? 36011012000 and 3.6*10^12

Comment: @pinegulf how can I split if I am not able to read it. I need a automated solution as  I cant perform manual steps on file.

Comment: Ah. I thought you had access to data source.

Answer (score 1):

That is an Excel problem, not a pandas problem. See here:

[image]

The yellow marked entries, are actually the number below * 10 +1 so should not end on 0.
[image]

What happens under the hood in Excel seems to be a number limit of 18. But the last two numbers are interpreted as decimals. Since this is a Excel not a CSV problem, a csv will work just fine.

**Solution:**

Format the numbers in Excel as Text, as shown in the first picture with: =Text(CELL,0).
Pandas can then import it as string, but you will lose the information of the last digits. Therefore Excel should not be used for numbers with more than 18 digits. Use a different file, like csv, insert the numbers directly as strings into excel by using a leading: '  symbol.